# Given the bilinear transform need to fine normal form of the bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra

Given following bilinear map 
$$2x_{1}x_{2} - 6x_{1}x_{4}-6x_{2}x_{3}+2x_{2}x_{4}$$
I have some trouble with finding orthogonal map 
I got the matrix of this transform and trying to find eigenvectors , but they are awful. So , I looking for another way to find ortgogonal map

Comment: Do you need basis, or just normal form? For normal form you don't need eigen vectors, only eigen values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the eigenvalues are unpleasant, I am guessing they want to make the Hessian matrix $H$ **congruent** to a diagonal matrix $D,$ in one direction $P^THP = D,$ the other $Q^T D Q = H,$ where $P,Q$ are nonsingular (and inverses)

The outcome is
$$ \frac{1}{2} (w+x-3y-2z)^2 - \frac{1}{2} (-w+x+3y-4z)^2  + \frac{3}{2} (-3y+2z)^2- \frac{27}{2} y^2$$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }  & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 3 & 1 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 3 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 27 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 3 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 27 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 3 &  - 4 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 3 & 1 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 3 & 1 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 3 & 1 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 1 &  - 3 &  - 2 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 3 & 1 \\ 
 - 3 &  - 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 &  - 3 &  - 2 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 2 \\ 
 - 3 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 2 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }  &  - 3 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 2 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }  &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 2 &  - 3 &  - 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 3 & 1 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 9 \\ 
0 & 2 &  - 9 &  - 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 3 &  - 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 9 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 9 & 6 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{7} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{7} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 3 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 3 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{7} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 3 &  - 4 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{7} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 6 &  - 9 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 9 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{8} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{8} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 3 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{8} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 3 &  - 4 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{8} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 27 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }  & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 3 & 1 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 3 &  \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 27 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 3 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 27 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 3 &  - 4 \\ 
0 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 3 & 1 \\ 
0 &  - 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Can you give me some resource or book where can I read about Hessian matrix?

Comment: @Yorn see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I have read information about this method, but i didn't understand how did you calculate E_{n}. Can you explain me, pls